# Is it possible to disable history (security & privacy menu) through the command line? What about location services?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I want to turn off the history switch (security & privacy menu) through the command line. Is it possible?

The following settings are set to false in gsettings if i disable it using the menu (gui), but the reverse doesn't happen (using gsettings):

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-app-usage "false"
>   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files "false"

The switch seems to be related to zeitgeist because if i delete ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/ the switch turns on again.

What about location service? Is there a way to disable it through terminal?

Thanks.